# Should Pardot Business Unit be either "region specific" or "product specific" or can it be both?

Tags: pardot, business-logic

Currently studying Pardot Business Units and was curious if a company ever uses a combination of both region and product specific B.U.'s. Just based off my research it seems that companies either use Region specific B.U.'s (America, International, Europe, etc.) or Product specific B.U.'s (home appliance, home entertainment, mobile, etc.).

Would it make sense for "X" company to have region specific B.U.'s, but to also have one for a specific product?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on how the company operates. Business Unit structure should ultimately reflect the organisation. I.e. in case there are individual marketing teams for each region, and they should not be able to see each others data, then Business Units should follow the same region specific division.

I will not recommend using a combination of region- and product specific Business Units, as it will be unnecessarily complex to switch these all the time, as I can't imagine a marketing team so specific, they can't work either across products within one region, or the other way around (across regions in single product area).